CodeIgniter 4 controller does not redirect after form submitted to database

I am migrating an old app I did in CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4. 
This app worked previously but not in CodeIgniter 4. 
After submitting the form below, the data is correctly getting inserted into a database, however it is not redirecting afterwards, it gets stuck. The URL just says /job and is a blank white page. If I echo $url at the bottom of add_job_detail() just before the redirect, as shown below. Then I get a blank white page with just result of $url correctly printed out. 
The issue I believe is that I am submitting the form to the controllers index, which then works out which submit button has been pressed and then routes to the relevant controller method.
Any one have any clues if this is what I am doing wrong. I don't see why it could be an issue as it was working with CodeIgniter 3.
I have got auto routing off. Form and URL helpers added to autoload.
Form from view:
<?php foreach ($job_details as $job_details_row): ?>
    <?php echo form_open('job'); ?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="job_details_id" value="<?php echo $job_details_row->job_details_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $job_row->job_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $job_row->company_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_number" value="<?php echo $job_row->job_number; ?>">

        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $job_details_row->quantity; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="details" value="<?php echo $job_details_row->details; ?>"></td>
        <td>
            £ <input type="text" name="price_each" value="<?php echo number_format($job_details_row->price_each, 2); ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" name="add_detail_button" value="Update">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/update_button.gif">
            </button>
            <button type="submit" name="remove_detail_button" value="Delete">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/delete_button.gif">
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Relevant part of controller when using add_detail_button:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Job extends BaseController
{
    protected $jobModel;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jobModel = new \App\Models\Job_model();
    }

    function index()
    {
        if (!$this->session->get('logged_in')) {
            return redirect()->to('');
        }

        if (isset($_POST['add_detail_button'])) {
            $this->add_job_detail();
        } else if (isset($_POST['remove_detail_button'])) {
            $this->remove_job_detail();
        }
    }

    function add_job_detail()
    {
        if (!$this->session->get('logged_in')) {
            return redirect()->to('');
        }

        $data = array(
            'job_id' => $this->request->getPost('job_id'),
            'quantity' => $this->request->getPost('quantity'),
            'details' => $this->request->getPost('details'),
            'price_each' => filter_var($this->request->getPost('price_each'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION)
        );

        $result = $this->jobModel->addJobDetails($data);

        $url = 'job/details/' . $this->request->getPost('company_id') . '/' . $this->request->getPost('job_id') . '/' . $this->request->getPost('job_number');

        if ($result) {
            echo $url;
            return redirect()->to($url);
        }
    }
}
?>

and routing:
$routes->get('/job', 'Job::index');
$routes->post('/job', 'Job::index');
$routes->get('/job/details/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)', 'Job::details');


If I change the $this->add_job_detail(); line in the index method to return $this->add_job_detail(); it does redirect. I think the problem is that your index method is not returning the RedirectResponse it gets from add_job_detail, and it needs to do that to be able to redirect, see the Important box here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/response.html#response-redirect

@Marleen Fantastic. That sorted it. Many thanks, it's working.
